# Combination of vectors' values with the same positional indices in R

Tags: r

Assuming we have the following simplified vectors (in reality, they contain much more values):

```
n <- c(1,2)
x <- c(4,5,6) 
y <- c(7,8,9)

#to get all possible combinations, we can use expand.grid 
df <- expand.grid(n=n,
                  x=x,
                  y=y
)

> df
   n x y
   1 4 7
   2 4 7
   1 5 7
   2 5 7
   1 6 7
   2 6 7
   1 4 8
   2 4 8
   1 5 8
   2 5 8
   1 6 8
   2 6 8
   1 4 9
   2 4 9
   1 5 9
   2 5 9
   1 6 9
   2 6 9
```

However, I would like vectors **x**, **y** to have the combination where only elements with the same index values are considered, i.e. (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3) but NOT (x1,y2), (x1,y3), etc.
while vector **n** is still used as usual (all its elements are 'paired' with the outcome of x and y combination).

In other words, I would like to get the following df:

```
   n x y
   1 4 7
   2 4 7
   1 5 8
   2 5 8
   1 6 9
   2 6 9
```

if **n** vector had 3 elements, i.e. n <- (1, 2, 3), then we would have:

```
   n x y
   1 4 7
   2 4 7
   3 4 7
   1 5 8
   2 5 8
   3 5 8
   1 6 9
   2 6 9
   3 6 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a function to do this

```
f1 <- function(vec1, vec2, n) {
       d1 <- data.frame(x = vec1, y = vec2)
       d2 <- transform(d1[rep(seq_len(nrow(d1)), each = length(n)), ], n = n)
        row.names(d2) <- NULL
        d2[c('n', 'x', 'y')]
  }



f1(x, y, n = 1:2)
#  n x y
#1 1 4 7
#2 2 4 7
#3 1 5 8
#4 2 5 8
#5 1 6 9
#6 2 6 9

f1(x, y, n = 1:3)
#  n x y
#1 1 4 7
#2 2 4 7
#3 3 4 7
#4 1 5 8
#5 2 5 8
#6 3 5 8
#7 1 6 9
#8 2 6 9
#9 3 6 9
```

---

Or in tidyverse

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tibble(x, y) %>% 
     uncount(length(n)) %>% 
     mutate(n = rep(n, length.out = n())) %>%
     select(n, x, y)
# A tibble: 9 x 3
#      n     x     y
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     4     7
#2     2     4     7
#3     3     4     7
#4     1     5     8
#5     2     5     8
#6     3     5     8
#7     1     6     9
#8     2     6     9
#9     3     6     9
```

Or create a `tibble` first and then use that with `crossing`

```
tibble(x, y) %>%
       crossing(n)
```

#### data

```
n <- 1:3
```

Comment: @ama I was following the same output as in andrewreece's solutioin

Comment: @ama yes, the updated codes are giving the pattern you showed

Answer (score 2):

You could combine list of pairs that need to be together and then use it in `expand.grid`

```
expand.grid(n, Map(c, x, y)) %>% tidyr::unnest_wider(Var2)
```

Or we can also use `crossing` using the same logic.

```
library(tidyverse)

crossing(n, x = map2(x, y, c)) %>%
  unnest_wider(x) %>%
  rename_at(-1, ~c("x", "y"))

#      n     x     y
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     4     7
#2     1     5     8
#3     1     6     9
#4     2     4     7
#5     2     5     8
#6     2     6     9
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tidyverse solution, using `purrr::map_df`:

```
library(tidyverse)

map_df(n, ~tibble(n=.x, x, y))

      n     x     y
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     4     7
2     1     5     8
3     1     6     9
4     2     4     7
5     2     5     8
6     2     6     9
```

If you need the values sorted exactly like your example output, add `%>% arrange(x, y)` to the output of `map`.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to paste together x and y, then use expand grid and separate the columns using the separate function from the tidyr package.

```
library(dplyr) #for pipe
library(tidyr) #for separate

n <- c(1,2)
x <- c(4,5,6) 
y <- c(7,8,9)
z <- paste(x, y, sep = "-")

expand.grid(n = n, xy = z) %>% 
  separate(xy, sep = "-", into = c("x", "y")) %>%
  mutate(x = as.numeric(x), y = as.numeric(y)) %>% 
  as.tibble()
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I am not sure if as.tibble() at the end is necessary. In any case, it seems that this is found in 'tibble' library.

Comment: No it's not entirely necessary, it was just to match the exact formatting of your output. Thanks